# How to detect touch on UIImageView and draw line?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I have create a ViewController and on Custom class I have selected myView. and in myView I have worked that when user click and drag finger it will draw a line straight line and when it drag again the previous line disappears and new one is created.

My code:

```
@implementation GestureView

{
    CGPoint _originOfTouchPoint; // your fist touch detected in touchesBegan: method
    CGPoint _currentFingerPositionPoint; // the position you have dragged your finger to
    CGFloat _strokeWidth; // the width of the line you wish to draw
    id _touchStartedObject; // the object(UIView) that the first touch was detected on
}

// If you use Interface Builder to design your interface, Objects in a nib file are reconstituted and then initialized using
// their initWithCoder: method
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:decoder];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        _originOfTouchPoint = CGPointMake( 0.0, 0.0 );
        _currentFingerPositionPoint = CGPointMake( 100.0, 100.0 );
        _strokeWidth = 2.0;
    }
    return self;
}
/*
 // Use initWithFrame if you are not loding the UIView from a nib file
 - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
 {
 self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
 if (self) {
 // Initialization code
 _originOfTouchPoint = CGPointMake( 0.0, 0.0 );
 _currentFingerPositionPoint = CGPointMake( 100.0, 100.0 );
 _strokeWidth = 2.0;
 }
 return self;
 }
 */

// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context    = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor( context, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor );
    CGContextSetLineWidth( context, _strokeWidth );
    // fisrt point of line
    CGContextMoveToPoint( context, _originOfTouchPoint.x, _originOfTouchPoint.y );
    // last point of line
    CGContextAddLineToPoint( context, _currentFingerPositionPoint.x, _currentFingerPositionPoint.y );
    // draw the line
    CGContextStrokePath( context );
}

#pragma mark touches

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    // get starting point and first view touched (if you need to send that view messages)
    _originOfTouchPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
    _touchStartedObject = [[touches anyObject] view];
}
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint movedToPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
    // if moved to a new point redraw the line
    if ( CGPointEqualToPoint( movedToPoint, _currentFingerPositionPoint ) == NO )
    {
        _currentFingerPositionPoint = movedToPoint;
        // calls drawRect: method to show updated line
        [self setNeedsDisplay];
    }
}
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    // reset values
    _originOfTouchPoint = CGPointZero;
    _currentFingerPositionPoint = CGPointZero;
    _touchStartedObject = nil;
}

@end
```

I have added 3 imageView on ViewController and I want to detect touch when the user click on any imageView and then when he drag his finger that line start drawing from that imageView.
I can draw line anywhere in the screen but I want to restrict just to draw line when click on imageView and ends on another imageView

[image]

[image]

Comment: Refer code inside link https://github.com/GrioSF/Android-Pattern-Lock-on-iOS

Comment: you must modify [touches anyObject], change anyObject with your uiimageview object

Answer (score 0):

You can enable touches with `-[UIView setUserInteractionEnabled:]` by default it's NO on `UIImageView`

About drawing... from docs:

> The UIImageView class is optimized to draw its images to the display.
>   UIImageView will not call drawRect: a subclass. If your subclass needs
>   custom drawing code, it is recommended you use UIView as the base
>   class.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    //To get tag of touch view
    int viewTag=[touch view].tag;

    if ([[touch view] isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
    {
      //Write your code...
    }
}
```

and set your all touch images UserInteractionEnabled like this:

```
[imageName setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```